# Convert windows device filename to drive letter

Tags: c, windows, file, winapi

I am trying to get the filename associated with a process handle in C, and since my code needs to run on Windows XP I'm using **GetProcessImageFileName** (rather than **QueryFullProcessImageName**).

However, **GetProcessImageFileName** returns the path in device form, e.g. \device\harddiskvolume0\ - how can I convert this to a drive letter?

Comment: Check this link in case this is what you are looking for:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366789(v=vs.85).aspx There is a function that looks like that do what you are asking

Comment: The only reliable method to do this going back to XP is GetModuleFileNameEx; unfortunately that will not work across 32-bit/64-bit boundaries.

Answer (score 3):

I was going to suggest [`GetModuleFileNameEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683198(v=vs.85).aspx) like Luke did in comments.

[`QueryDosDevice()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365461(v=vs.85).aspx) on all drive letters (you can find all the drive letters with [`GetLogicalDrives()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364972(v=vs.85).aspx)) would be another bet, though it's theoretically possible that you could get a path without a drive letter, or symbolic links could screw up a straightforward string compare.

But..  How about this...  You should be able to prefix the NT path with `\??\GLOBALROOT` (this is from memory, it might not be exactly that) and then use it in functions like `CreateFileW()`.  (AFAIK it has to be the Unicode versions of the file APIs..)

Comment: This is a really old post, but surprisingly, the results that show up when googling for this, are depressing. You are correct. You can prefix the device path with ```\\.\GLOBALROOT``` and you can access files. From there you can use ```CreateFile()``` with ```OPEN_EXISTING``` to get a handle, and using that handle, you can call ```GetFinalPathNameByHandle()``` to get the DOS path.

Answer (score -1):

You can try convert the drive letter form to device form instead, and here is what I did, hope it helps:

```
    TCHAR szTemp[MAX_PATH] = {0};
    _tcsncpy(szTemp, lpszImageFile, 2);
    QueryDosDevice(szTemp, szImageFile, MAX_PATH);

    _tcsncat(szImageFile, lpszImageFile+2, _tcslen(lpszImageFile) - 2);
```

In this code, lpszImageFile is the full path name of the process, e.g. c:\program files\test.exe.